# Software for detecting orange dates on 4x6" photo prints and adding to metadata

Tags: metadata, digitizing, date

Is there any software that will detect (e.g., OCR) the orange date timestamps burned into 4x6" snapshot prints and automatically add the date EXIF metadata? Would be interested in options either baked into the scanning software or that can be applied to a batch of files post-scanning. If this exists, it's very hard to search for it (not sure if that burned-in orange date feature has a name).

Comment: Timestamp is the term, Photographic prints with Timestamps.   I think you will have to use your eyes, brain and fingers.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Since the location of the timestamp is fixed, it should be straightforward to write a script to extract it (imagemagick), OCR (tesseract), and edit exif (exiftool).